# Solving Green's function with Dirichlet boundary Conditions

Tags: greens-function

I'm trying to solve this integral.

$$
\int_0^\infty dx' \int_{-\infty}^\infty dy' \frac{1}{((x-x')²+(y-y')² +z²)^{3/2}}
$$ 
I wasn't able to come up with a proper substitution yet.

This integral is an attempt to solve the Potential of a point charge in the half space V := {$\textbf{r} \in \mathbb{R}^3| z \geq 0$} on the surface $\partial V$ = {$ \textbf{r} \in \mathbb{R}^3|z = 0 $} with Dirichlet Boundary Condition for the Green function with the method of images.

Where 
\begin{equation}
    \phi(\textbf{r})=
    \begin{cases}
      0, & \textbf{r} \in \partial V, x<0\\
      \Phi, & \textbf{r} \in \partial V, x\geq0
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$ \forall A>0,\qquad \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dy'}{\left(A+(y-y')^2\right)^{3/2}}=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dy'}{\left(A+y^2\right)^{3/2}}=\frac{2}{A}\tag{1} $$
the given integral equals
$$ 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx'}{(x-x')^2+z^2}=\frac{2}{|z|}\int_{-x/|z|}^{+\infty}\frac{dx'}{x'^2+1^2}=\frac{2}{|z|}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan\frac{x}{|z|}\right).\tag{2}$$